# Binning for line charts in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, linechart

I have data recording ancient olympic events with year data. I'd like to create a line chart where the x-axis is binned years (let's say decades) and then each of the lines is the sum of events within the bin.

The data looks like

```
Row 01| -476 | Stadion
Row 02| -476 | Boxing
Row 03| -476 | Pankration
...
Row 10| -434 | Stadion
Row 11| -433 | Boxing
Row 12| -433 | Stadion
```

The resulting graph would show a line for each event (the last column) with a sum of the count of the number of that event within a configurable bin. Here's a mockup of what I'm imagining:
[image]

Is that possible in Google Sheets?

Comment: Man one would hope google has this, if it doesn't I wonder if you could hook that data it into chart.js to render the lines.

Comment: Would you be able to provide your sample sheet [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can further help you?

Comment: Sure, it's just a table copied from Wikipedia: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EIq-SkRoS-oRUh2NxtxVG-lnaZUjTwU4eAuT0L_cpcY/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to write your own histogram components, which are:

- compute the intervals (we will use min of each intervals)
- aggregate counts
- generate x-axis labels and plot line chart

##### compute the intervals

In your examples, you have manually entered select intervals.

If you want to automatically assign intervals based on the number of "bins" and automatically cover the whole series, you can use `sequence` in conjunction `arrayformula`. Suppose `K4` is the number of "bins" you manually define. The following formula outputs a column array representing the left boundaries of the intervals.

```js
=arrayformula(floor(K2+(max(C2:C)-min(C2:C))/K4*sequence(K4,1,0,1)))
```

[image]

##### aggregate counts

Next is to aggregate counts for each intervals. There are many ways to accomplish this. The simplest is to use `counta` and `filter` and "dragging", as shown below.

To make the formula as simple as possible, we also append `1e99` to the end of the intervals using inline array via `{...;...}` notation.

[image]

You can further centralize the formula with `map` and `offset`. (And with this particular implementation you do not need to append `1e99` on the interval column.)

```js
=map(L2:L,lambda(c,if(isblank(c),,
       counta(filter(C2:C,D2:D=D$2,
                          C2:C>=c,
                          C2:C<if(isblank(offset(c,1,0)),1E+99,offset(c,1,0)))))))
```

[image]

##### plotting

To connect the histogram data to Google Sheet's line chart, you want to provide the series of x-axis labels corresponding to each "bin". The label part can be done, for example, by

```js
=arrayformula(if(isblank(L2:L),,if(isblank(L3:L),L2:L&" to "&K3,L2:L&" to "&L3:L)))
```

(This implementation assumes no appended `1e99`.)

You can then select the range with the histogram values and the x-axis labels, and with the range highlighted, Insert -> Chart. (In the example below, you need to have `N2:O4` highlighted.) And then select line graph. You see see all the options having been set by Google Sheet to use the data. If not, you can toggle them yourself as shown below

[image]

Comment: Wow that's amazingly thorough. Thank you for the excellent answer, unfortunately this is a bit complicated for what I was hoping to do. This was supposed to be for an in-class exercise for students first getting into quantitative analysis. I'll have to think about a simpler way to accomplish this.

Comment: @labarna: Maybe ask them to preprocess the data so that there is only one set of input into Google Sheet line graph? Manual definition of the bin intervals and then using `filter` can be one such example. Separately, there should be online tools for outputting histogram parameters in 1 step. Matlab (the programming language) has it if students are using school computers that have Matlab installed. Good luck!